# Powerbi equivalent to SQL having function

Tags: report, powerbi

Im a trainee working with databases.

Im working on PowerBI report based on SQL query where all of the needed joins are included for my data to be obtained. So Im working within one dataset.

I have made a table where I can show number of transaction(like invoice number) and name of person that made that transaction. My problem lies in creating a measure that will influence that table. It should work like a having clausule from SQL (well at least my boss said that).
I would like for this measure to force this table to show only data for people that have made more than 2 transactions (they have more than 2 invoice numbers [so there are more than two rows for this person]) .

I tried to do it by writing a measure like that:

```
Measure = COUNTAX(
Query1;counta([Salesman])>2)
```

Or like that:

```
Measure 2 = 
FILTER( Query1; counta(Query1[Salesman])>2 )
```

But i only got a bar graph that is showing me how many transactions were made by each person. When Im adding this measure to this table i see that for each row i got value 1.

Im new to the PowerBi and DAX so it's quite a big hurdle for me. Can someone share his/hers knowledge to help solve this problem? I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.
I created a second query that counted transactions for each person with their names. I created relationship between my two queries. Next I added counting attribute to my table with data from query one and I used filter on my counting attribute. After that this attribute can be just hidden and It works perfectly.

On top of that I created a measure and made a chart using this measure. It looks nice and clear.

The measure looks like that:

```
Measure = 
        COUNTAX(
            Query1;counta([Salesman])
                )
```

I filtered this measure too to get wanted result.